# Node.js can't get JSON Object property

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm using Node v6.5.0. I have a JSON Object as the response of HTTP request and I need to get the body property. However if I try to get the body using `res.body`, I will get completely messed up result.

Because the JSON Object is too long, I can't post it here. Follows is the link of coderpad containing the JSON Object and the result when I access the body property

https://coderpad.io/6RNEMTJ3

Comment: What is the issue? you are getting body in  the HTML form

Comment: Reduce the json to just `{"foo": "bar"}` post a minimal example of your code and tell us what module you are using to fetch the json

Comment: @abdulbarik. It's not the same as on the JSON Object (clearly it's an invalid html)

Comment: Maybe, you are requesting a secure page but sending request without credentials since it seems to login page.

Comment: No, it's not a secure page that needs credetials. On the JSON Object's body (line 17), you can see that the HTML is valid. But if I try to get `res.body` (line 362), it's not a valid HTML. I can get the valid HTML using zombie.js, but it uses a lot of memory

Answer (score 0):

The only body I can see in your coderpad link seems to be a string containing HTML. Which can't be parsed as JSON.

Comment: How can I parse it?